# Es posible que se reduzca el tamaño de un archivo, solo con acomodar código?

Tags: c, archivo

Lo que quiero decir es:
Que al empezar había escrito mi código en el main, luego decidí hacer una función y acomodarlo allí. Lo raro no es eso sino que antes de crear la función pesaba 150 KiBy luego de crear y ordenarlo pesaba 130KiB.
Es eso posible?  .

Comment: ¿Te refieres al archivo con el código fuente o al ejecutable generado al compilar?

Comment: El archivo con el codigo fuente.

Comment: puede haber variaciones según el encoding del texto y el tipo de salto de línea, además de la posibilidad de que el editor cambie las tabulaciones por espacios ( o al reves ) o elimina espacios extra de cada línea, o al final del archivo. un `diff archivo1 archivo2` debería darte una pista

Comment: El archivo con el código fuente es un simple fichero de texto, si tiene menos bytes es que tiene menos caracteres (o caracteres que ocupan menos bytes si es una codificación de longitud variable como UTF-8). Como bien comenta alo Malbarez, la reducción dependerá de la codificación usada, lo que determina el número de bytes para representar un carácter dado.

Comment: otra es si el disco tiene mas de 64 terabytes y formato ntfs, o 32 gigabytes y fat32 o exfat =P

Comment: Gracias me han ayudao mucho, busqué pero salían cosas confusas.